# Identify change of state of individual in panel data using pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by, panel

I have panel data (repeated observations per ID at different points in time). Data is unbalanced (there are gaps). I need to identify for a change in variable per person over time.

Here is the code to generate the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "region": ["C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C2"],
        "id": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        "date": ["01/01/2021", "01/02/2021", "01/01/2021", "01/02/2021", "01/03/2021"],
        "job": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B"],
        "wage": [10, 10, 15, 25, 25],
        "change": [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
    }
)


df
```

I am trying to generate the "change" column, and have not been able to have an efficient solution.
Thanks for any help!

I have tried the following:

```
df['change']=df.groupby(['id'])['job'].diff().fillna(0)
```

But it is giving me the following error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: what is the expected output? added an answer, if that is what you're after

Comment: The expected output is the "change" column (last column). I am trying to generate the "change" column, which happens due to change in job status, i.e. from A to B for id=2.

Comment: did the added answer helps?

Comment: No, the proposed solution is for a numeric variable while the change is due to change in status of a categorical variable. The expected output is the "change" column (last column). I am trying to generate the "change" column, which happens due to change in job status, i.e. from A to B for id=2. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: can you post the expected out as a table?

Answer (score 0):

```
# groupby id and use diff to see difference in wage from previous wage

df['money_difference']=df.groupby(['id'])['wage'].diff().fillna(0)
df
```

```
   region   id       date   job     wage    change  money_difference
0   C1      1   01/01/2021    A     10           0  0.0
1   C1      1   01/02/2021    A     10           0  0.0
2   C2      2   01/01/2021    A     15           0  0.0
3   C2      2   01/02/2021    B     25           1  10.0
4   C2      2   01/03/2021    B     25           0  0.0
```